# The Products link on the SO top banner looks out of place when hovered over

Tags: discussion, bug, hyperlinks

I've just noticed that the "Products" link a the top of SO has a rounded border when I hover over it with my mouse:

[image: Products link with rounded border on mouse hover]

Is there anywhere else on the site where a link has a rounded border on hover? Excuse me if this is just me being pedantic, but I can't remember anywhere else on the website with such a rounded border and it seems inconsistent with the rest of the top banner (and the rest of the site AFAICR).

On a related note, it has a different hover colour to other links on the top banner (`#e4e6e8` vs `#eff0f1`). Is there a reason for this inconsistency?

---

**Regarding the opinion-based close votes:**

I'm not looking for an opinion-based discussion on whether or not this was a good design choice; I'm looking for a confirmation whether or not the decision to make this link different to every other link on the site (that I can remember at least) was deliberate or not.

Inconsistencies like this stick out to me like a sore thumb so I'd like to know the reasons behind why this is different - setting a precedent for styling all over your website and then breaking that without good reason doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Drawing attention to pages that few visitors would consider looking at was the goal.  Seems to work.

Comment: @HansPassant maybe I am just overly-sensitive to things like this, but to me it feels uncomfortably different. Like, there are ways to make something deliberately different in keeping with the general theme of the site, and unless I'm forgetting something I can't remember any other links on the entire site which look like this.

Comment: Regarding the close votes, I'm looking for a more definitive "this was a deliberate decision and here's why" or "the fact that this doesn't fit with the styling of the website was an oversight/visual bug/whatever" - maybe I didn't phrase my question correctly (and maybe it's ambitious to expect a real staff answer to this stuff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that when logged out, the Products link does in fact fit with the rest of the banner links:

[image: Screenshot of the Stack Overflow homepage when logged out, showing that the Products link isn't the only one with rounded edges]

However, the fact that the link/button/whatever styling isn't in keeping with the rest of the site (when logged in at least) bugs me. Especially as there is no differentiation between a dropdown menu (such as the Products button) and a hyperlink (such as the Customers or Use cases links).

Until (if ever) a SO designer responds though, I'll mark this question as answered.